# Can't add contributors on github

Tags: github

When I try to add a collaborator on a private github repo, I get this error "You can't perform that action at this time."

That's cruelly vague, why is not possible to do so ?
I only got one more private repo and there's only two collaborators on other repos.

[screenshot from github](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kHJwQ.png)

Comment: A screenshot would be better

Comment: How do I upload it here ?

Comment: In the edit section of this question you will find a image icon click that and select the image you want to upload

Comment: Try using email

Comment: It gives the same result

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was caused by my adblocker extension, after disabling it it works well !

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried Googling? Is it possible it was a temporary hiccup with Github?

Additionally, you may want to refresh to ensure you're still logged in.

Comment: I googled it and found nothing very helpful, I also try to disconnect/reconnect my session and even restarted my computer.

It's not the first time I get this error, it seems random to me

Comment: I found that on github's doc : "Note: In a private repository, repository owners can only grant write access to collaborators. Collaborators can't have read-only access to repositories owned by a user account."
But I don't think it's relevant here, I can't read or write, I can't add a collaborator

Comment: people dont come here to be asked to "google it"